# Intents in a grid instead of a list on Android 4.4 KitKat

Tags: nexus-4, 4.4-kitkat, intents

I have just received the Nexus 4's Android 4.4 KitKat OTA. One of the first things I remarked was that the intents layout for choosing an application is now a list instead of a grid just like in Jelly Bean:

[image: New intent layout]
<sup>(click for larger image)</sup>

I find this list layout ugly (I don't want to go back to the good ol' ICS days) and I would like to get my intents in a grid again. How can I retrieve the grid layout for intents on Android 4.4 KitKat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want something like this:

[image: AppChooser]
<sup>*AppChooser* (source: Google Play; click for larger variant)</sup>

Freely configurable, including the possibility to...

- switch between list and grid
- hide apps you never use, but still having them available quickly with a single tap
- sort alphabetically or by last-used

Then take a look at [AppChooser Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/appchooser-pro/jp.co.noxi.apppickerpro), available for a single buck. There's also a free version on Play if you want to test it first. I went immediately for the payed version a couple of months ago, and never regretted the decision. Still you might wish to pick the free version first, as I didn't test it on 4.4 (I'm still on 4.0 on my phone).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will test this solution and write a feed back in the comments. However I would prefer a solution without third party apps so that's why I do not accept it now.

Comment: Understood. I had prefered a "stock solution" as well. But either I've overlooked it, or there really is no possibility to configure the picker. Wouldn't be the first time I missed a "hidden gem", so let's see whether someone turns up with an alternative; if not, you still can accept the answer later (or accept now, and *switch* the accept-flag later, if a better solution is presented).